# wxWidget which button (wxButton) was pressed?

Tags: c++, event-handling, wxwidgets

I am trying to create an array of buttons by using this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    wxButton *btn_random = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, _T("Button " + std::to_string(i)), wxPoint(250, 10*i + 10*i), wxSize(60, 25), 0);

    btn_random->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, &MyFrame::OnPressed, this);
}
```

In the function OnPressed(wxCommandEvent& event) I can get the unique Id of the button, but I want to change and modify the button inside the OnPressed function. How do I do that?

Also, I have read that it is possible to cast a wxWindow when using wxWindow::GetWindowById(id) but I cannot get this method to work.

Comment: Instead of `wxID_ANY` you should provide specific unique ID of this button, so you will be able to determine which button was pressed.

Comment: @Arkady It is assigned an unique ID by using wxID_ANY. I have also tried with wxNewId() but that gave duplicates(like 0 and 0 or 32724 and 32724) at times. When I print event->GetId() it is unique for each button inside the OnPressed function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.GetEventObject()` to retrieve the object which generated the event. You will need to (`dynamic_`-) cast it to the correct type, however. If you'd rather avoid this, you need to use fixed IDs, e.g. `MY_BUTTON_OFFSET + i` and store the button pointers yourself somewhere and then use `event.GetId() - MY_BUTTON_OFFSET` as index for retrieving them.

P.S. Nothing to do with your question, but `wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED` is long and unwieldy and exists for compatibility only nowadays, just use `wxEVT_BUTTON` instead.